# Pivot on same column multiple times in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I have searched through the site, and even though there are multiple questions regarding this problem, either I can't fully understand them as I am a really newbie in SQL or they don't fully suit my issue.

So I have a table like this:

```
ID  Label   AmountA AmountB CurrA   CurrB
1   7         400   4        usd    usd
2   7         500   10       eur    eur
3   7         1000  500      usd    usd
1   8         800   1        usd    usd
2   8         9000  0        eur    eur
3   9         100   0        usd    usd
```

But I need it like this:

```
ID  AmountA1    CurrAmountA1    AmountA2    CurrAmountA2    AmountA3    CurrAmountA3    AmountB1    CurrAmountB1    AmountB2    CurrAmountB2    AmountB3    CurrAmountB3
 1  400         USD             800         USD             NULL        NULL            4            USD            1            USD            NULL        NULL
 2  500         EUR             9000        EUR             NULL        NULL            10           EUR            0            EUR            NULL        NULL
 3  1000        USD             NULL        NULL            100         USD             500          USD            NULL         NULL           0           USD
```

I have managed to do the following code:

```
SELECT ID,
isnull([7],0) as AmountA1, 
isnull([8],0) as AmountA2, 
isnull([9],0) as AmountA3, 
FROM 
(SELECT ID, Label, AmountA, AmountB,CurrA, CurrB FROM mytable ) ps
PIVOT
( sum([AmountA]) FOR Label IN
( [7], 
[8], 
[9])) as pvt
```

Where I am only getting the AmountA pivoted, but I can't figure out a way on how to include the other ones.

I don't know if it is worth to say that I need to do this on millions of rows, and the Label can have 10 different values, and I need it to be as fast as possible.

Thanks

Comment: check this -- https://stackoverflow.com/q/27707421/5496498

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this query. SQL Server don't let us give an Alias to the pivot column in the subclause Pivot. So to avoid pivot conflict column error, we can do a "work around" declaring many Label columns and concat a value to create another kind of Label. Finally, we group by Id column since we have many equal IDs in the table.

Here the link where I tested this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/26a01/6

```
Select ID, Max(isnull([7],0)) as AmountA7, 
           max(isnull([7-3],0)) as CurrA7, 
           max(isnull([8],0)) as AmountA8, 
           max(isnull([8-3],0)) as CurrA8, 
           max(isnull([9],0)) as AmountA9, 
           max(isnull([9-3],0)) as CurrA9, 
           max(isnull([7-2],0)) as AmountB7, 
           max(isnull([7-4],0)) as CurrB7, 
           max(isnull([8-2],0)) as AmountB8, 
           max(isnull([8-4],0)) as CurrB8, 
           max(isnull([9-2],0)) as AmountB9, 
           max(isnull([9-4],0)) as CurrB9
  from
( 
 select Label LabelAAmount, CONCAT(Label, '-2') LabelBAmount, CONCAT(Label,'-3') LabelACurr, CONCAT(Label, '-4') LabelBCurr, ID, AmountA, AmountB, CurrA, CurrB
  from myTable
) ps
PIVOT
(Sum(AmountA) for LabelAAmount IN ([7],
                                     [8],
                                     [9])
) as pvtAmountA
pivot
(Sum(AmountB) for LabelBAmount in ([7-2],
                                   [8-2],
                                   [9-2])
) as pvtAmountB                      
pivot
(Max(CurrA) for LabelACurr in ([7-3],
                               [8-3],
                               [9-3])
) as pvtCurrA
pivot
(Max(CurrB) for LabelBCurr in ([7-4],
                               [8-4],
                               [9-4])
) as pvtCurrB
group by id
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then amountA end) as amountA_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then currA end) as currA_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then amountA end) as amountA_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then currA end) as currA_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then amountA end) as amountA_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then currA end) as currA_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then amountB end) as amountB_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then currB end) as currB_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then amountB end) as amountB_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then currB end) as currB_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then amountB end) as amountB_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then currB end) as currB_3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by label) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```