# SQL Pivot table, with multiple pivots on criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, aggregate, pivot-table

Here is my dataset,
[image]

It has a reservation (unique ID) a reservation_dt a fiscal year (all the same year for the most part) month both numerical and name as well as a reservation status then it has total number reserved followed by a counter (basically
1 for each reservation row)

these are my guidelines (they need to be turned into columns by Month)

- Requested - Count of All Distinct reservations
- Num_Requested (sum total_number_requested by month)
- Booked (count of All Distinct reservations status is order created)
  Num_Booked (sum total_number_requested by month) where status is order created
- Not_Booked (count of All Distinct reservations where status unfulfilled)
- Not_Num_Booked,   (sum total_number_requested by month where status is unfulfilled)

I am looking to translate this into a pivot table and this is what I've got so far and can't figure out why its not working.

I figured I would turn each of the above guidlines into a column, using either sum(total_number_Requested) or count(total_requested) where reseravation status is ... and such.
I'm open to any other ideas of how to make this simpler and make it work.

```sql
SELECT [month_name],
       fyear AS fyear,
       Requested,
       Num_Requested
FROM (SELECT reservation,
             reservation_status,
             total_number_requested,
             fyear,
             [month_name],
             [month],
             total_requested
      FROM #temp2) SourceTable
PIVOT (SUM(total_number_requested)
       FOR reservation_status IN ([Requested])) PivotNumbRequested PIVOT(COUNT(reservation)
       FOR total_requested IN ([Num_Requested])) PivotCountRequested
WHERE [month] = 7
ORDER BY fyear,
         [month];
```

Comment: Honestly, I would recommend looking at conditional aggregation over the far more restrictive `PIVOT` operator; you may well find it a lot easier.

Comment: If you supply *consumable* sample data (not an image) and your expected results, that will also greatly help others help you.

Comment: Why do fields with numeric data appear to be text type? I would remove "fy" from fyear data and make this a number field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional expressions to emulate data pivot. Example:

```
SELECT fyear, Month, Monthname, Count(*) AS CountALL, Sum(total_number_requested) AS TotNum, 
Sum(IIf(reservation_status = "Order Created", total_number_Requested, Null)) AS SumCreated
FROM tablename
GROUP BY fyear, Month, MonthName
```

More info:
[SQLServer - Multiple PIVOT on same columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27707421/sqlserver-multiple-pivot-on-same-columns)
[Crosstab Query on multiple data points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46548072/crosstab-query-on-multiple-data-points)