# Access SQL: concatenate rows containing a specific value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a table which will list part assemblies and their constituent parts. I have made some code which will do this but in this example I get 7 rows when I want only 2 (the PartDefID and PartClass columns will be hidden the the DGV that displays the table). Each row should contain parts that have the same AssemblyID although several parts may reside on the same row.
The code I have so far is:

```
SELECT Parts.PartDefID, PartDefinitions.PartClass, Parts.AssemblyID, PartDefinitions.PartNumber, PartDefinitions.PartDescription, PartDefinitions.KitNumber
FROM Parts INNER JOIN PartDefinitions ON Parts.PartDefID = PartDefinitions.PartDefID
WHERE PartDefinitions.PartClass = 1 OR PartDefinitions.PartClass = 3 OR PartDefinitions.PartClass = 4 OR PartDefinitions.PartClass = 5 OR PartDefinitions.PartClass = 6 AND Reference = 0;
```

this gives me a table that looks like this:

```
PartDefID      PartClass  AssemblyID                                    PartNumber      PartDescription                                   KitNumber
68             1          {86d99c66-3cc3-40cf-9489-7be7838f90c8}        330-00366-78    GI275 P1                                          011-04809-00
23             3          {86d99c66-3cc3-40cf-9489-7be7838f90c8}        011-00950-04     Sub-Assy, Backshell w/Hdw, 50/78 pin   
2              1          {17e17f78-731a-4828-972b-be91c06eb149}        MS27467T23F55P   Connector, circular 55 pin 
31             3          {17e17f78-731a-4828-972b-be91c06eb149}        M85049-49-2-22N  Sub-Assy, Backshell w/Hdw, 55 pin circular 
41             6          {86d99c66-3cc3-40cf-9489-7be7838f90c8}        011-04038-00     Sub-Assy, Config Mdl, w/EEPROM, Jackscrew, 2Mbit   
32             4          {86d99c66-3cc3-40cf-9489-7be7838f90c8}        011-01169-00     Sub-Assy, Shield block w/Hdw, shell size 1-3   
34             5          {86d99c66-3cc3-40cf-9489-7be7838f90c8}        117-00004-00     Locking tab 9, 15, 25, 37
```

What I want is a table that looks like this:

```
PartDefID       PartClass    AssemblyID                                 PartNumber      PartDescription              Backshell        Shield block   Slide lock      Config module   KitNumber
68              1            {86d99c66-3cc3-40cf-9489-7be7838f90c8}     330-00366-78    GI275 P1                     011-00950-04     011-01169-00   117-00004-00    011-04038-00    011-04809-00
2               1            {17e17f78-731a-4828-972b-be91c06eb149}     MS27467T23F55P  Connector, circular 55 pin   M85049-49-2-22N
```

In the table I want, the "backshell" column is the partnumber for partclass 3, the "shield block" column is the partnumber of partclass 4, the "slide lock" column is the partnumber of partclass 5 and the "config module" column is the partnumber partclass 6. The only part descriptions that would be listed then would be those for partclass 1 which is the parent part.
I think it's doable, but out of my league.
Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Sample data should be provided as text tables, not images.

Comment: SO does not allow attaching files and discourages links to resources - all info needed to evaluate issue should be within question. Images can be hard to read and tables built within question can be copy/pasted. Alternatively, provide CREATE sql. Moot point now as I have provided an answer without building tables to test. But keep in mind for future.

Comment: agreed, text could be cut&paste from here to build tables with, a picture does not do that. Tried to cut the data from a spreadsheet, but it created a picture when pasted

Comment: Copy/paste Access table results in text that will need some additional formatting. Review https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow

Comment: Your question title references concatenation but I don't see any concatenation code. Why does desired output show more fields than the wrong output?

Comment: the concatenation part is what I am missing, concatenation probably a bad choice of words. the columns in the table that I want which do not appear in the original need to be created on the fly, perhaps with the "AS" keyword. So the column called "backshell" for example in the top row would contain the part number in the row which also contains a partclass of 3 and the same assemblyID as that of the top row. Sorry, I know this sounds confusing.

Comment: That's not concatenating, it's aggregating and pivoting, as what a CROSSTAB query is used for. A CROSSTAB can be emulated with conditional expressions and GROUP clause.

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses are critical when mixing OR and AND operators - think how parentheses are considered in algebraic rules of order of operations. Your query WHERE CLAUSE logic is "return all records where (PartClass equals 1 or 3 or 4 or 5) or (PartClass equals 6 and Reference equals 0)" - even though your query has no parentheses, that's the logic that will be followed - perform operations left to right.

Possibly you want:

```
WHERE (PartDefinitions.PartClass = 1 
OR PartDefinitions.PartClass = 3 
OR PartDefinitions.PartClass = 4 
OR PartDefinitions.PartClass = 5 
OR PartDefinitions.PartClass = 6) 
AND Reference = 0;
```

or
`WHERE PartClass IN (1, 3, 4, 5, 6) AND Reference = 0`

Now only records that have any of those PartClass values AND have Reference of 0 will be retrieved. You don't show Reference field so assuming only records 68 and 2 have 0, then only those 2 will retrieve.

If there are only 6 PartClass values, could simplify:

`WHERE PartClass <> 2 AND Reference = 0`

Now, in light of clarification in comments, producing the desired output would involve either:

1. a CROSSTAB query - use Access query designer, there is even a wizard for CROSSTAB; more info about CROSSTAB http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html
2. emulate a CROSSTAB with conditional expressions to calculate fields and use GROUP BY to compress - example in [SQL Pivot table, with multiple pivots on criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70804530/sql-pivot-table-with-multiple-pivots-on-criteria) - one expression for your data: `Backshell: First(IIf([PartClass]=3, [PartNumber], Null))`

Comment: point on parens taken. There are other part classes so using a "not" operator would be just as long.

Comment: Edited answer with another syntax.

Comment: "WHERE PartClass IN (1, 3, 4, 5, 6) AND Reference = 0" that does look MUCH better. Still gets more than the two rows required though.

Comment: Then there is something about data needs clarification. Again, Reference field was not included. What is its data type?

Comment: the reference field is just a boolean, or zero/non zero

Comment: Did you see additional edit to my answer?

Comment: I see your links to a couple of other articles, I haven't dived into them yet.