# Query to count different fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with the following values:

Date of creation
IDNumber
Type of expte (can be "1" or "30")
Author (5 different options)
Sent to print (Date when it was sent)
Critics (5 different values)
Critic Date (Date when the critic was published)

And I want to create a query which, given a period of time (the query should ask for "Date from" and "Date until" and the user can type whatever they want; for instance: from 01/01/2022 to 16/01/2022) it gives the following results:

- Number of exptes created in that period of time that are Type "1"
- Number of exptes created in that period of time that are Type "30"
- Number of exptes created in that period of time that are Type "1" created by Author "A"
- Number of exptes created in that period of time that are Type "1" created by Author "B"
- Number of exptes created in that period of time that are Type "1" created by Author "C"
- Number of exptes created in that period of time that are Type "1" created by Author "D"
- Number of exptes created in that period of time that are Type "1" created by Author "E"
- Number of exptes created in that period of time that are Type "30" created by Author "A"
- Number of exptes created in that period of time that are Type "30" created by Author "B"
- Number of exptes created in that period of time that are Type "30" created by Author "C"
- Number of exptes created in that period of time that are Type "30" created by Author "D"
- Number of exptes created in that period of time that are Type "30" created by Author "E"
- Number of exptes sent to print in that period of time (but they could have been created in other period of time)
- Critics received in that period of time which have value "1"
- Critics received in that period of time which have value "2"
- Critics received in that period of time which have value "3"
- Critics received in that period of time which have value "4"
- Critics received in that period of time which have value "5"

I am very noob in access and the db was created by someone is already retired so I don't know how to do that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide any code that you have already tried, additionally, and sample data you have available would really help in assisting your question.

Comment: Your question makes sense. Since it apparently is about MS Office "Access", perhaps adding a few tags like `ms-access` and its version number could help to get more precise feedback

Comment: i think its better to create an view or stored procedure who receives the dates and generates an projection, so you can use anywhere just with a `exec myProcedure` or `select * from myView`

Comment: What do you mean when you say "exptes", is that a typo perhaps?

Comment: Exptes meaning records or dossiers (sorry, my English is awful)

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn sorry, I haven't tried anything. Only want to know if want i described is possible (i suposse so but i don't know where to start)

Comment: ¡Hola @Requeixo !No problem at all. My English is also not perfect, but I think your question will get better/ more helpful feedback if either you or someone would correct the typos. What do you think?

Comment: Si, you can do that in MS Access (any version I'd say). When you write "where should I start", can you tell more about which part of the task(s) you described looks difficult to you, for example programming the UI part where the users of your software are supposed to tell the Type "1" or "30" etc., or is it about the SQL you would need for the .mdb query, or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Pivot table, with multiple pivots on criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70804530/sql-pivot-table-with-multiple-pivots-on-criteria)

Comment: Attempt query and edit question to show it. Apply WHERE clause with date range parameters. Best to reference form controls for user input. I doubt all of these outputs can be done with one query. The counts might doable in one query using method described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70804530/sql-pivot-table-with-multiple-pivots-on-criteria but retrieving critics that meet a single value would involve 5 queries. Or build a report and use its Sorting & Grouping features.

Comment: I finally managed to do it by using several queries and then I put all the results in one final query. After that I created a report based on that final query.  I have a lot to learn about access; but i do start to like it. Many thanks to everybody