# How to merge multiple rows into columns using left joins

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm currently stuck trying to write a query in MS Access using multiple left joins.

It should merge the results of a query with the data of an existing table.
Table "Adressen" contains an unique identifier which should be used for the LEFT JOIN.
"q_TestMatchen" however has multiple rows per uuid, one for each [betreiber], which means that there can be uuids where no data for [betreiber] = "Carrier1" is available.

Eventually I want to have one row per [uuid] with the matched columns of "q_TestMatchen" appended at the end.

I hope that this makes sense so far.

Below is my current code:

```
SELECT q.*, v.betreiber, v.ist_down, v.ist_up, v.ist_tech, v.plan_down, v.plan_up, t.betreiber, t.ist_down, t.ist_up, t.ist_tech, t.plan_down, t.plan_up
FROM (Adressen AS q 
LEFT JOIN q_TestMatchen AS v ON q.uuid = v.uuid)
LEFT JOIN q_TestMatchen AS t ON q.uuid = t.uuid 

WHERE (q.[betreiber] IS NULL AND IIF(v.[betreiber] IS NOT NULL, v.[betreiber] = "Carrier1", 1) AND t.[betreiber] = "Carrier2") AND q.fa <> 0;
```

This is what the result of the input query "q_TestMatchen" looks like (same columns as in table "Adressen", but the fields 'betreiber', 'ist_down' etc. are empty there):

| uuid | x | y | .... | betreiber | ist_down | ist_up | ..... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DETEST1234 | 23.4567 | 45.2345 | .... | carrier1 | 250 | .... |  |
| DETEST1234 | 23.4567 | 45.2345 | .... | carrier2 | 1000 | .... |  |
| DETEST1235 | 23.6789 | 45.3456 | .... | carrier2 | 1000 | .... |  |
| DETEST1236 | 23.3456 | 45.1523 | .... | carrier1 | 500 | .... |  |
| DETEST1236 | 23.3456 | 45.1523 | .... | carrier2 | 100 | .... |  |

This is what I want the table to look like in the end:

| uuid | x | y | .... | v.betreiber | v.ist_down | .... | t.betreiber | t.ist_down | ..... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DETEST1234 | 23.4567 | 45.2345 | .... | carrier1 | 250 | .... | carrier2 | 1000 | .... |
| DETEST1235 | 23.6789 | 45.3456 | .... |  |  | .... | carrier2 | 1000 | .... |
| DETEST1236 | 23.3456 | 45.1523 | .... | carrier1 | 500 | .... | carrier2 | 100 | .... |

The code above is working, but it generates two rows per uuid, which is not what i eventually want it to be.

Thanks for your help in advance. Best Regards, Michael

Comment: Edit question to show sample data as text tables as well as desired output.  "rows into columns" sounds like a CROSSTAB PIVOT.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @June7, I've added the table layout to the description. Hope this helps

Comment: Didn't ask for sample of unwanted output, but for sample of raw data tables.

Comment: Which it is, as I wrote

Comment: Well, I am not going to try deciphering what is provided to figure out data structure to build tables. Apparently the 'many' side of a relationship is included and that results in 'duplicates'. Suggest you explore CROSSTAB query, start with http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70804530/sql-pivot-table-with-multiple-pivots-on-criteria.