# Dynamic Pivot multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a query where I am pulling this data in separately to pivot. I have 3 different pivot queries to join them together at the end of my script. (One for the date, bool, and code responses)

[image]

After I pull in the date data (before I pivot it looks like this: The date, column title is label, and the Row id.

[image]

What I would like to do is pivot all three together into one pivot instead of three different pivots.

So I would have these columns:

Row_ID, Addendum Included_Date (which contains the date), Addendum Included_Bool (which contains the bool), Addendum Included_Code (which contains the code), Application Complete Date_Date (which contains the date), etc, through all the column names.

Is this possible?

[image]

I'm looking for something similar to this.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Add tag for RDBMS used.

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70804530/sql-pivot-table-with-multiple-pivots-on-criteria

Comment: The above sample is just for one record out of thousands. I don't want to sum the data. I need it pivoted to display.