Use SQL to combine multiple Crosstab query results into individual Bins (ranges)
I have an Excel worksheet that shows counts of 11 Bins (column ranges) - see image - that result from one Access data set.  Instead of linking from Excel, I want to do this in Access.  I can create individual queries - no problem.  I have created a Crosstab query for each of the 11 Bins as well.  The image is of 1 of the CT queries.  To get a result like the Excel result I have to then design a second query with the 11 CT results, then add each of those "rows" as a separate field.  I just know that running nested queries in a query is not the right approach.   While it works, it is incredibly inefficient and consumes a lot of resources.  I'm certain there is a SQL solution - not UNION - where the script will perform each of the 11 crosstabs using the Bin criteria, then creating the array.   I'm great at Excel and good at Access VBA, but not much experience in SQL.  Please help (and be patient).

SO is a "code-assistance" site - you have not provided code for analysis. You have not even provided sample raw data (as formatted text table, not image). Therefore question is not appropriate for SO. What you want can probably be done with CROSSTAB (with calculated field to generate the header "bins") or an emulated CROSSTAB (with 11 calculated fields using IIf(), Switch(), or Choose()). Unfortunately there is not enough information to advise.

Some resources: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64400911/pivot-query-in-ms-access, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70804530/sql-pivot-table-with-multiple-pivots-on-criteria, http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html.

I do apologize; I had no SQL starting point so nothing I could offer to evaluate.   I do have the query structures, and I prefer to not use VBA.    I guess I can run each of the 11 Crosstabs, then take each of their SQL statements and run a series of select queries all in one script.   Doesn't seem like I gain anything however.    Sorry to have submitted this.   All my prior questions (under a different user email) had VBA code to evaluate.   This one didn't, so I will retract.

This should be possible without running 11 CROSSTABs or using VBA, I just don't have enough information.

Thank you June7;  I think you have helped.   I will try iif() in the expressions and see if I can collect each of the 11 in one query; that seems rational.   BTW, with my other user name "TheProhaskaGroup" one of your earlier solutions has been working magnificantly!

To show the SQL of your attempted query, open the query in SQL View (not Design View) as you show. Then copy/paste that content into the body of your post.

So the bins differ for each of the 11 CTs? Do all CTs reside in same table with a distinguishing column? Would help to know what specifically differs between the 11 queries? Please post a couple of SQL statements.

thanks Parfait - let me log on to my work VPN and extract the code.   to answer the Q:  same table, same field being used as the Row and Column of crosstab (you can see that in the image), and the count is the number of records in each.   The only difference is the  calculated field (far right of image - design view).  i.e.  the next CT criteria is >15 and <= 20, and so on.

TRANSFORM Count(tblBreakOut.CREDID) AS CountOfCREDID
SELECT tblBreakOut.CURRENTSTATE
FROM tblBreakOut
WHERE (((tblBreakOut.CREDENTIALTYPE)<>"MEDICAL CERTIFICATE") AND
((tblBreakOut.LAST_STATE_CHANGE)>#12/31/2023#) AND
(((Date()-[last_state_change])+[nettime])>8 And ((Date()-[last_state_change])+[nettime])<=15))
GROUP BY tblBreakOut.CURRENTSTATE
PIVOT tblBreakOut.CURRENTSTATE;

Consider conditional aggregation (portable to other databases) by converting your WHERE calculated condition into a calculated SELECT column using IIF() to flag the data that is then summed to count the flags. You can also include other aggregates like the count of records.
SELECT 
    CURRENT_STATE AS State,
    COUNT(CREDID) AS Volume,
    SUM(IIF([Days Ac] BETWEEN 0 AND 8, 1, 0)) AS [0 - 8 Days Ac],
    SUM(IIF([Days Ac] BETWEEN 9 AND 15, 1, 0)) AS [9 - 15 Days Ac],
    SUM(IIF([Days Ac] BETWEEN 16 AND 20, 1, 0)) AS [16 - 20 Days Ac],
    SUM(IIF([Days Ac] BETWEEN 21 AND 25, 1, 0)) AS [21 - 25 Days Ac],
    SUM(IIF([Days Ac] BETWEEN 26 AND 30, 1, 0)) AS [26 - 30 Days Ac],
    SUM(IIF([Days Ac] BETWEEN 31 AND 40, 1, 0)) AS [31 - 40 Days Ac],
    SUM(IIF([Days Ac] BETWEEN 41 AND 60, 1, 0)) AS [41 - 60 Days Ac],
    SUM(IIF([Days Ac] BETWEEN 61 AND 90, 1, 0)) AS [61 - 90 Days Ac],
    SUM(IIF([Days Ac] BETWEEN 91 AND 110, 1, 0)) AS [91 - 110 Days Ac],
    SUM(IIF([Days Ac] BETWEEN 111 AND 130, 1, 0)) AS [111 - 130 Days Ac],
    SUM(IIF([Days Ac] > 130, 1, 0)) AS [>130 Days Ac]
    SUM(IIF([Days Ac] IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS [CheckValue]
FROM (
   SELECT 
       CURRENT_STATE,
       CREDID,
       Date() - [last_state_changed] + [nettime] AS [Days Ac]
   FROM tblBreakOut
) sub
GROUP BY CURRENT_STATE 

However, MS Access' crosstab can still work if you calculate the bins beforehand using nested IIF(). See how string values of calculated column in inner query become pivoted columns in outer query.
TRANSFORM COUNT(CREDID) AS [Count]
SELECT 
   CURRENT_STATE AS [State],
   COUNT(CREDID) AS [Volume]
FROM (
   SELECT 
       CURRENT_STATE, 
       CREDID,
       Date() - [last_state_changed] + [nettime] AS [Days Ac],
       IIF([Days Ac] BETWEEN 0 AND 8, '0 - 8 Days Ac',
        IIF([Days Ac] BETWEEN 9 AND 15,'9 - 15 Days Ac',
         IIF([Days Ac] BETWEEN 16 AND 20, '16 - 20 Days Ac',   
          IIF([Days Ac] BETWEEN 21 AND 25, '21 - 25 Days Ac',        
           IIF([Days Ac] BETWEEN 26 AND 30, '26 - 30 Days Ac',          
            IIF([Days Ac] BETWEEN 31 AND 40, '31 - 40 Days Ac',
             IIF([Days Ac] BETWEEN 41 AND 60, '41 - 60 Days Ac',
              IIF([Days Ac] BETWEEN 61 AND 90, '61 - 90 Days Ac',
               IIF([Days Ac] BETWEEN 91 AND 110, '91 - 110 Days Ac',
                IIF([Days Ac] BETWEEN 111 AND 130, '111 - 130 Days Ac',
                 IIF([Days Ac] > 130, '>130 Days Ac',
                  IIF([Days Ac] IS NOT NULL, 'CheckValue', NULL)
                 )
                )
               )
              )
             )
            )
           )
          )
         )
        )  
       ) AS [Days Ac Bin] 
   FROM tblBreakOut
) sub
GROUP BY CURRENT_STATE
PIVOT [Days Ac Bin] IN (
    [0 - 8 Days Ac],
    [9 - 15 Days Ac],
    [16 - 20 Days Ac],
    [21 - 25 Days Ac],
    [26 - 30 Days Ac],
    [31 - 40 Days Ac],
    [41 - 60 Days Ac],
    [61 - 90 Days Ac],
    [91 - 110 Days Ac],
    [111 - 130 Days Ac],
    [>130 Days Ac],
    [CheckValue]
)


Notice how Access allows aliased columns in other expressions within same SELECT for compact writing (one rare perk of Access SQL).

Thank you, Parfait; let me digest this and try it out; probably feedback tomorrow.

It did not like the second "AS [Days Ac]" after iif closing parens.   I'm not familiar with your "sub" statement but it appears to have created a second table

Whoops! I fixed that naming issue in crosstab. In both querues, sub is a subquery and should not create a new table in database.

Thank you Parfait!   I made a couple of tweaks and it now works perfectly!!    Thank you for your expert assist!!   Have a good Holiday season.
