# SQL Pivot Multiple Columns Teradata

Tags: sql, pivot, teradata

I have a set of data taking snapshots of schedule dates at the beginning of the month (BOM) and end of the month (EOM). I need to pivot the data so the dates are columns instead of rows. I can't figure out how to do this with multiple columns. Any ideas?

[Current Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vE6k1.png)

[Desired Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNaEw.png)

I have tried pivoting the data but only know how to pivot one column, not all of the date columns shown.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't use images to show data, put it in your post as text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLServer - Multiple PIVOT on same columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27707421/sqlserver-multiple-pivot-on-same-columns)

Comment: You could use *conditional aggregation* with MIN/MAX (which is what PIVOT would be rewritten as "under the covers"), or for this simple case you could use self-join.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.